# ColdFusion Socket Gateway

Tags: coldfusion, websocket

What is the performance like on a Socket Gateway for CF?

**EDIT :**

I meant to ask, given the way its built is it suitable for large scale applications or just demo purposes? I.e 2000+ users being connected to it, but small amounts of data coming in and going at various times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the parameters that you include, acceptable.

Edit: Sorry about the snark.

So, in general the performance has been pretty good, and from my experience with it, as long as your setup could handle 2000 requests via the typical web facing request, the socket gateway should be able to hold up, depending on what exactly you are doing with it.

From a networking perspective, you have to be careful about holding 2000 ports open if that's what you're doing.

In any case I would recommend load testing.

Comment: i meant to ask the way its built is it built to for large scale applications or just demo purposes.

Comment: Cool that makes sense. Basically Im just trying to get my java clients to connect to this port and get CF to store the clients identification, and once in a while tell the client something. Ill try some load testing, any suggestion how I would simulate 2000+ connections to the gateway?